# Jquery hovers all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement jquery hover function into my div elements, so I have a div that firstly it is not shown , so i hide it with css, `display:none` and i am using jquery hover to show it, so this is my code

```
$('.fc-day-grid-event').hover(
  function() {
    $(".hidenDiv").css("display", "inline-block");
  },
  function() {
    $(".hidenDiv").css("display", "none");
  }
);
```

but when i hover through the element , all elements with the class `.fc-day-grid-event` shows the hidden div , it should show the `hidenDiv` only in the element that i hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Use* Context Selector or `.find()` to target the child of current `fc-day-grid-event` element

```
$('.fc-day-grid-event').hover(function () {
    $(".hidenDiv", this).css("display", "inline-block");
    //$(this).find(".hidenDiv").css("display", "inline-block");
}, function () {
    $(".hidenDiv", this).css("display", "none");
});
```